# Can I run an MVC app and WCF Web Api on the same AppHarbor site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-web-api, appharbor

We have a solution with this structure.

- OurApp.Web (mvc 3 project with controllers, views)
- OurApp.Api (mvc 3 project with wcf web api service classes)
- OurApp.Domain (entities, repositories, unit of work, etc)
- OurApp.Tests (tests)

We want to use a dns structured like this:

http://www.ourapp.com points to OurApp.Web

http://api.ourapp.com points to OurApp.Api

We want to host on [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/).

How can we do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AppHarbor currently only supports deploying *one* application from any given repository. One option might be to fold the API into the web project. I did this for a non-web API WCF service [here](https://github.com/friism/folketsting/blob/master/FolketsTing/Global.asax.cs#L25).

Another option is to maintain two AppHarbor applications, and use solution files named according to what application you want deployed for that application. That is, `OurApp.Web.sln` contains the Web project and any supporting projects and, `OurApp.Api.sln` references the API project and any supporting projects. Read more about [AppHarbor solution file convention](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention).

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Comment: +1 for looking for a solution file named as the application's slug (and the ".sln" suffix). Never knew that. Only knew about appharbor.sln. #LOVE